# Changing minimum mapping unit for CORINE project on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to identify roads on files from the CORINE project but since the minimum mapping unit is 25 ha, I have very few objects.

How can I change on QGIS the minimum mapping unit from 25 ha to 5ha?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `raster` layer, you will of course be able to change raster resolution - [here is a way to do so](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGgzrLbhn5s). But because the initial data / resolution will remain 25 ha minimum mapping unit it **will just be an artefact** with no added values. The algorithm is able to split a cell but will not guess what is inside these new created small cells - it will just take value from the initial cell (the bigger one) and dispatch it into smaller ones ...

As reminder, I will provide that link https://sdi.eea.europa.eu/catalogue/geoss/api/records/71c95a07-e296-44fc-b22b-415f42acfdf0 :

> CLC datasets are based on the classification of satellite images produced by the national teams of the participating countries - the EEA members and cooperating countries (EEA39). National CLC inventories are then further integrated into a seamless land cover map of Europe. The resulting European database relies on standard methodology and nomenclature with following base parameters: 44 classes in the hierarchical 3-level CLC nomenclature; minimum mapping unit (MMU) for status layers is 25 hectares; minimum width of linear elements is 100 metres. Change layers have higher resolution, i.e. minimum mapping unit (MMU) is 5 hectares for Land Cover Changes (LCC), and the minimum width of linear elements is 100 metres.

According to your needs, you may find some interesting data (5ha MMU) on `change layers`. See following page : https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover and [manual](https://land.copernicus.eu/user-corner/technical-library/manual_of_changes_final_draft.pdf).

Comment: Ok, thank you very very much for this great and helpful answer! it seems that I will be able to use neither rasters nor CLC change since roads widths are never larger than 100 metres... I think that I will try to rasterise archives of maps...